# Purpose of `[NOTFOUND=continue]` in nsswitch.conf?

Tags: unix, nsswitch.conf

I see the following configuration in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
shadow:     files [NOTFOUND=continue] ldap
```

Is there any purpose to the `[NOTFOUND=continue]` action? Isn't this functionally the same as the following configuration, which is far more common:

```
shadow:     files ldap
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly different - it means it will only continue if the account was not found.

If the account is present in the file, but an invalid password was supplied - then the trail stops there.